# Внести данные из массива в готовую таблицу html

Tags: html, jquery

Есть обычная таблица html вида 4*4:

```
<table class="class_1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="wrapper_1">
            <!-- сюда нужно внести данные-->
        </div>
</td>
<!-- 4 ячейки -->
</tr>
<!-- 4 строки -->
```

Нужно внести данные из массива (ниже) в таблицу выше.

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d', 'e','f','g','h', 'i','j','k','l', 'm','n','o','p'];
```

Для обычного внесения чисел использовал:

```
var i=1;
jQuery(".wrapper_1").each(function(){
            jQuery(this).append('<span>'+i+'</span>');
            i++;
        });
```

Как повторить с ассоциативным масивом также? Повторюсь, нужно именно добавлять новый html элемент в уже существующую таблицу.

**Решение:**

```
 jQuery.each(array, function(index, value){               
        jQuery('.wrapper_1:eq('+index+')').append('<span>'+value+'</span>');
    });
```

Comment: `var w = $(".wrapper_1");` а в цикле вызываете `$("<span/>").text(i).appendTo(w);`

Comment: Это похоже на то что я написал выше для чисел, насколько я понимаю нужно делать такого плана:
///
jQuery.each(array, function(index, value){
  jQuery(".wrapper_1").append('<span>'+value+'</span>'); 
});

Comment: var w = $(".wrapper_1"); array.forEach(function(el) { $("span/>").text(el).appendTo(w); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего контейнера:

```
<div class="wrapper_1"></div>
```

Обход нумерованного массива:

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d', 'e','f','g','h', 'i','j','k','l', 'm','n','o','p'];
array.forEach(function(el, i){
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper_1')[0];
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<span>' + el + '</span>, ';
})
```

Результат:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p,
```

Обход ассоциативного массива:

```
var array2 = {'a':'element a', 'b':'element b', 'c':'element c'};
for(var key in array2){
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper_1')[0];
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<span>' + array2[key] + '</span>, ';
}
```

Результат:

```
element a, element b, element c,
```

Comment: Почти jQuery ;) Спасибо за мысль.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Уже отвык от jQuery. Думаю, обращение к элементу можно заменить на селектор, и использовать append().

Comment: Добавил решение к вопросу, как сделал я :)

Comment: C jQuery лаконичнее смотрится =)